# Converting a SharePoint SPListItem into a Drop down ListItem

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-list

I am trying to convert a SharePoint `SPListItem` into a `ListItem` to put into a Drop Down List. My problem is that the data in the SharePoint list is stored like this:

> ;#Daylight;#
>
> ;#Design;#Employee Engagement;#

But Obviously this does not work for me. I need to remove the ;# symbols which should be as simple as `String.Replace` but where I am running into some problems is what should I do for list items that contain multiple selections (my second example above). The ultimate goal here is to generate a drop down list (that does not contain duplicates) of all the items in the SharePoint List. Any ideas?

```
        using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url.ToString()))
        using (SPWeb oWebsiteRoot = site.OpenWeb())
        {
            SPList oList = oWebsiteRoot.Lists["WplData"];
            SPListItemCollection items = null;
            SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
            query.Query = "<Where><IsNotNull><FieldRef Name='Topic' /></IsNotNull>" +
                "</Where><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Topic' Ascending='True' /></OrderBy>";
            items = oList.GetItems(query);
            DataTable tmpTable = new System.Data.DataTable();
            tmpTable = items.GetDataTable();
            DataView view = new DataView(tmpTable);
            String[] columns = { "Topic" };
            DataTable table = view.ToTable(true, columns);
            foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
            {
                foreach (var item in row.ItemArray)
                {
                    ListItem listItem = new ListItem();
                    listItem.Value = item.ToString();
                    listItem.Text = item.ToString();
                    TopicDropDownList.Items.Add(listItem);
                }
            }
       }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of a DataTable, try [SPFieldLookupValueCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldlookupvaluecollection%28v=office.12%29.aspx):

```
SPList oList = oWebsiteRoot.Lists["WplData"];
SPListItemCollection items = null;
SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
query.Query = "<Where><IsNotNull><FieldRef Name='Topic' /></IsNotNull>" +
    "</Where><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Topic' Ascending='True' /></OrderBy>";
items = oList.GetItems(query);
foreach (SPListItem item in items)
{
    SPFieldLookupValueCollection values = 
        new SPFieldLookupValueCollection(item["Topic"].ToString());
    foreach (SPFieldLookupValue value in values)
    {
        ListItem listItem = new ListItem();
        listItem.Value = value.LookupId.ToString();
        listItem.Text = value.LookupValue;
        TopicDropDownList.Items.Add(listItem);
    }
}
```

Note, since you specified SharePoint 2007, I am avoiding the use of LINQ because that requires the .NET Framework 3.5. Also, as long as each list item contains a distinct set of topics, you will be fine. But if topics can be repeated among list items, you will want to modify this code so that `TopicDropDownList` contains a distinct set of topics.

Answer (score 0):

LINQ it, something like (psuedocode)

```
...
var ddlItems = (from i in items
             select i["Topic"]).Distinct();
TopicDropDownList.Items.AddRange(ddlItems);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

If *Topic* is a multi-choice field you can split the field value by `;#`:

```
var listItems = items.Cast<SPListItem>()
  .SelectMany(i => Convert.ToString(i["Topic"]).Split(";#", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
  .Distinct();

TopicDropDownList.Items.AddRange(listItems);
```

You can directly operate on the `SPListItemCollection` returned by `oList.GetItems(query)`. You do not need to convert it in a `DataTable`.

You might considering including the *Topic* field as `ViewField` in your query.

If you don't want to split the field value manually, you could use the [SPFieldMultiChoiceValue class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms415672.aspx). Unfortunately there is no handy way to access the choices in this class. There is only a count and an indexer so you have to use a for-loop.